# Was ist ein Urke?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Im Buch „Der Boxer“ von Szczepan Twardoch kommt hin und wieder das Wort Urke vor. Ich habe keine Ahnung, was das bedeutet und finde auch keine Referenzen online dazu.

Der Roman (Übersetzung aus dem Polnischen) spielt in Polen kurz vor dem Zweiten Weltkrieg vorwiegend in der jüdischen Gemeinde.

Hier ist ein Zitat, in welchem das Wort vorkommt:

> Der Pate […] sah ihn beim Training, sprach ihn an und erkannte sofort den Straßenjungen in ihm, den Urke.

(Das steht genau so im Roman. Es fehlt kein n.)

Ich habe nach Orten gesucht, von denen sich Urke ableiten könnte, aber nichts gefunden. Eventuell handelt es sich um einen jiddischen oder polnischen Begriff. Was bedeutet Urke?

Comment: Altes Küchenlatein "urca" - *auftauchen, aufsteigen*? Litauisch "žiurkė" = *Ratte*, das ungefähr wie unser "Schurke" ausgesprochen wird und möglicherweise auch dessen Herkunft ist?

Comment: @tofro  DWB: "schurke , m. nichtswürdiger mensch. im hochd. seit dem 16. jahrh. bezeugt, doch findet sich schon ahd. virscurgo furcifer [...], welches offenbar eine nominalbildung zu ferscurgan, repellere, ist [...]. zusammenhang beider wörter ist nicht wol zu bezweifeln; auffallend bleibt dabei weniger das vollständige fehlen von zeugnissen aus der mhd. zeit, als die durchgängige verhärtung des g zu k. [...]. im nhd. ist schurke in der schriftsprache sehr gewöhnlich, scheint dagegen in den mundarten nicht beliebt zu sein." - Die litauische Ratte finde ich also nach wie vor erforschenswert.

Comment: Versuch die Recherche mal unter der Annahme, dass es sich um einen Begriff aus dem Rotwelschen, nicht dem Jiddischen handelt... : https://books.google.de/books?id=3Og6Jp8XmOEC&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=urke+rotwelsch&source=bl&ots=Tbetj5BvuX&sig=Tjioidkm0uNzhNsiTDmgW7UdKa0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNvpifl93ZAhXDvhQKHe_lAYkQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=urke%20rotwelsch&f=false

Comment: @Mac: finde ich sehr interessant, mach doch eine Antwort daraus!

Comment: Ich habe die E-Mail-Adresse des Übersetzers ausfindig gemacht und ihm die Frage mal geschickt. Mal schauen...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mir fiel heute ein, den Übersetzer Olaf Kühl einfach direkt anzuschreiben. Er hat mir soeben folgendes zum Wort "Urke" geschrieben:

> "Urke" kommt aus dem Russisch-Jiddischen und heißt dort "Gangster",
>   "Dieb" ("урка"). Twardoch übernimmt es auch einfach so, im Polnischen
>   werden viele es ebenso wenig verstehen. Ich habe dann recherchiert und
>   in einigen speziellen Texten das "Urke" gefunden. Ein bißchen Exotik
>   muß sein.

Viele Kommentare sind auf der richtigen Spur.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Danke, habe ich soeben gemacht

Answer (score 4):

Nach einigem Herumrecherchieren (und einem im Frühstadium abgebrochenen Versuch, den Autor des Romans zu kontaktieren<sup>1</sup>) habe ich nun meine aus Polen stammende Kollegin gefragt, der das Wort zunächst nichts sagte, doch sie hat sich wiederum bei ihren Freundinnen erkundigt. Demnach wird das Wort

> Urke

im Polnischen verwendet als **Bezeichnung für einen Ganoven, Übeltäter oder eben Schurken**.

Die Freundinnen meiner Kollegin verweisen ebenfalls auf den bereits in Kommentaren hier genannten berühmten **Urke Nachalnik**, meinen aber, dass *Urke* auch als eine Bezeichnung für Spitzbuben allgemein gebräuchlich sei.

Damit könnte man den inkriminierten Satz auch so fassen:

> Der Pate […] sah ihn beim Training, sprach ihn an und erkannte sofort den Straßenjungen in ihm, den Tunichtgut.

Da es zum Thema passt, darf ich hier vielleicht  noch auf eine schöne Bezeichung für einen solchen Übeltäter hinweisen, der in Bulgarien gebräuchlich ist, nämlich den

> нехранимайковец / nechranimajkovec

also den "Ernährt-seine-alte-Mutter-nicht-ler", also ein Typ von der ganz herzlosen Sorte, auf Neudeutsch vielleicht kurz - wenn auch weniger pittoresk - ein

> Assi

oder, wenn man Vokabular des frühen 19. Jahrhunderts lieber mag, ein

> Taugenichts

Interessant noch: *Urke Nachalnik* könnte man demnach auch als

> Schurke Frechdachs

übersetzen.

<sub>1) Seine Website wird bei mir von Firefox als Malware-verseucht gemeldet (8.3.2018). So ein urke!</sub>

Comment: Der Name ist anscheinend ein Künstlername und wird auf einigen englischsprachigen Seiten mal als "brazen master criminal", mal als "Crafty Master Thief" übersetzt. (Google "urke", "yiddish"). Evtl. lässt sich auch das englische "urchin" damit in Beziehung bringen?

Comment: ... nach kurzem Geistesblitz noch was gefunden (wenn man das Ganze nicht über Jiddisch, sondern eher über Rotwelsch aufzieht): https://books.google.de/books?id=3Og6Jp8XmOEC&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=urke+rotwelsch&source=bl&ots=Tbetj5BvuX&sig=Tjioidkm0uNzhNsiTDmgW7UdKa0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNvpifl93ZAhXDvhQKHe_lAYkQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=urke%20rotwelsch&f=false

Comment: @Mac  Interessant; aber führt vielleicht auch im Kreis herum: "Rotwelsch ist die im 13. Jahrhundert entstandene Geheimsprache der Gauner, deren Wortschatz zum Teil auf Sonderbedeutungen bekannter Worte, vor allem aber auf umgedeuteten Anleihen ***aus dem Jiddischen*** und aus Zigeunersprachen basiert." - Gibt es hier vielleicht jemanden, der des Jiddischen ausreichend mächtig ist?

Answer (score 2):

**Urke** ist ein Eigenname als Referenz, in diesem Fall bezieht sich das wohl auf [Urke Nakhalnik](http://www.yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Nakhalnik_Urke).

Comment: Neben dem Namen gibt es noch eine zweite Bedeutung. Die Zeitschrift, die ich abonniere, kostet pro Monat 3 Urke 50.

Comment: @Pollitzer  In Deutschland, in Polen, oder in welchem Währungsterrain?

Comment: @Pollitzer, nur wird nicht nach irgendeiner Bedeutung gefragt, sondern nach der, die der Romanautor im Sinne hatte.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Nicht Schilda, nicht Nimmerland – Phantasialand.

Comment: @Pollitzer  Na ja, aber wo sagt man denn "3 Urke 50"? Hörst du das irgendwo? Liest du es irgendwo? In der Schildaer Neuen Presse? Im Nimmerländer Volksfreund?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich finde diese Seite gar nicht... Normalerweise kommen solche Hinweise von nicht bezahlten Gebühren für Sicherheitszertifikate, das ist also noch nicht direkt ein Hinweis auf Gefahr.

Comment: @RoyPJ - Du findest den Link zu des Autors Website indem du die ihm gewidmete polnische Wikipedia-Seite aufsuchst: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szczepan_Twardoch  Da ist ganz unten der Link zu seiner Website ("strona autorska")

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Danke, ich kann somit mit 99%iger Sicherheit sagen, dass die Seite sicher ist :)